# AWS EC2 becomes "Other Linux" from Ubuntu when creating AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-ami

I did the following steps:

```
   1) Use an existing AMI with Ubuntu 16.0.
   2) Create Instance from this AMI and Launch it.
   3) Do nothing, just stop the instance.
   4) Create AMI from this stopped instance.
```

The new AMI becomes (Platform) "Other Linux" and I cannot login into SSH into anymore......:
   When using Putty, I can see on terminal output 'instance XXX connected',
   but do not have access the terminal Bash.
   (just read only screen).

It happens anytime when I used another AMI than Amazon AMI (Ubuntu).

Is it related to Free tier account ?
How to get support on this ?

Thanks vm.

Similar issues:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=758595#758595

Comment: You seem to skip some steps in your question after you created the AMI. Did you create a new instance from the AMI, and you can't login to that instance? Or did you start the old instance again, and now you can't login to that instance? What exactly can't you login to? Also, this is not related to the fact that you are try to keep your account within the free tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (using  AWS Support...):
Pb was due to AWS Mindterm Java SSH Browser which cannot connect to this instance.

But using Putty works well, "Other Linux" does not have influence.

```
1.) Other Linux means No vanilla Ubuntu (default Ubuntu changed).
2.) Can be connect to EC VM using Putty
     putty -ssh  loginName@Ipadress

Dont forget to convert PEM file to PPK using PuttyGen 1st.
login depends on the original AMI instance, 
here ubuntu/root can be used since this is Ubuntu Amazon.
```

Compare to google Cloud, AWS does not have robust Web Browser SSH, so 3rd party SSH is needed.